# How to hide ribbon row for non-admin users?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, css

I have removed ribbonrow for nonadmin users using the following Code:

```
Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="ManageWeb">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
 </script>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

and this:

```
<div id=”s4-ribbonrow” class=”s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle” style=”display:none”>
```

It is working fine, with no ManageWeb permission i cannot see the ribbon, but i I owe this permission i.e Administrator I can the the ribbonrow only in homepage if I go to another subsite I cannot see the ribbonrow. How to fix this up?

Comment: possibly the permissions are being checked for the web where the master page is hosted, as opposed to the "current" web

Comment: @TiagoDuarte I apologize for my poor knowledge of SharePoint could you be more specific please?

Comment: are you admin on the subsite?

Comment: yes I am fully admin in all sharepoint

Comment: @TiagoDuarte thanks mate for your help. I have reset masterpage inherits for all subsites and now it is working Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the properties of SPSecurityTrimmedControl is [PermissionContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.permissioncontext.aspx).

Not sure what the default is, but you may try and set it to "RootSite" or "CurrentSite" according to where you want the permissions to look when opening a site.

> Possible values are:
>
> PermissionContext.**CurrentFolder**
>
> PermissionContext.**CurrentItem**
>
> PermissionContext.**CurrentList**
>
> PermissionContext.**CurrentSite**
>
> PermissionContext.**RootSite**

[image]